# No tables to add in database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem using databases in visual studio.

- I created a new windows form project
- I added a new item, a service based database
- In the server explorer and in the solution explorer a new databases was added
- The dataconnection was made
- The datasource is Microsoft Sql server database file
- The database file is the newly added .mdf file in the project directory

My problem:

When I right click tables, I cannot add new tables.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What do you mean you cannot add new tables? Is there no "Add" command in the context menu, or is the "Add" command disabled, or is the "Add" command enabled but clicking it doesn't work?

Comment: I will remember for the next time.

Comment: There is no add table option. Only a refresh and properties options

Comment: This is the same for all database folders.

Comment: Same issue here.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks back.
(I use visual studio 2015.)

In visual studio check what type of visual studio you have. (help -> about Microsoft Visual Studio).
I don't know what I had but now I have "Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015".

Instead of "Enterprise" there was another type of visual studio 2015 that looked exactly the same but couldn't add tables.

All you have to do is redownload visual studio 2015, but the enterprise type.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It's been almost a year but I ran into the same probelm but fixed it by installing SQL Server Data Tools

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396